# Xeon memory bandwidth specification incongruency

Tags: memory, cpu, bandwidth, xeon

How can [this Xeon](http://ark.intel.com/products/84681/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E7-8867-v3-45M-Cache-2_50-GHz) achieve the stated 102 GB / s memory bandwidth with the following configuration:

> Channels: 4
>
> Type: DDR4-1866

The max. theoretical bandwidth would be 59.712 GB / s. The stated figure is approx. 71% higher.

Comment: How are you getting that number? A single DDR4-1866 channel is about 30GB/s. 4 of them is about 120GB/s.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I get my figures from Wikipedia. I don't know where you get yours from. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_device_bit_rates (kindly remove the downvote)

Comment: I don't see *channel* bandwidth anywhere on the Wikipedia page. I do see module bandwidth. Are you assuming they're the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are computing DDR4 *module* bandwidth and using that as bandwidth of the CPU's memory controller channel. This is only valid if each of the CPU's four memory channels were somehow limited to only talking to one DDR4 module at a time. This is not true for this architecture. On typical implementations, each SMB (scalable memory buffer) that connects to the SMI (scalable memory interface) channel can talk to two memory modules at a time.